# Add Elements to a Searchable Dropdown That Weren't Originally in the Dropdown - Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, dropdown, html-select, searchable-dropdown

How can I add an input box into a `select` element, with Vue?

Let's say I've got a list like `['Red', 'Yellow', 'Green']`, and the user wants to choose 'Black' which not in the list.

I want the user to be able to type it, within the select element, get it added to the list, and be selected.

Here is my code so far:

```js
<template>
  <div >
     <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <label >Colors</label>
            <select v-model="selected" class="form-control" >
              <option v-for="option in list"  class="form-control" :key="option">
                  {{ option}}
              </option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <p>The selected color is: {{selected}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
      return{
      list:['Red', 'Yellow', 'Green'],
      selected: '',
    };
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to add more options to the select or what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to create list of predefined options, and let the user add free text in case none of the options is relevant

Comment: Can you be more specific? It's hard to answer this without knowing the context.

Comment: Assume my list is ['Red', 'Yellow', 'Green'], and the user wants to choose 'Black' which not in the list. I want the user can type it and to get it as input

Comment: It's really dependent on your use-case. What you're asking at the moment is as simple as adding a text input which is bound to its own data property. What you do with the data after it's been inputted and how it affects other functionality on the page is what's important. Could you post the rest of the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`vue-multiselect`](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/) for the searchable dropdown:

```html
<multiselect
  :options="list"
  v-model="selected"
></multiselect>
```

...and add some custom code to add the typed color to `list` when **Enter** or **Return** is pressed:

```html
<div @keyup.enter="addColor($event)">
  <multiselect
    :options="list"
    v-model="selected"
    @search-change="typed = $event"
  ></multiselect>
</div>
```

```js
addColor() {
  if (!this.list.includes(this.typed)) this.list.push(this.typed); // check if inputted color is already in the list; if not, add it; if so, don't
  this.selected = this.typed; // set `selected` to the currently typed color
},
```

[image: demo]

Note that you will have to add the CSS for vue-multiselect, which you can see how to do in the installation instructions [here](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-getting-started).

[Sandbox & Full Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-fast-kwrgs?file=/src/App.vue:0-798)

Comment: Thank you! But yet it doesn't in the same element but two.

Comment: @DanielKahalani -  I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean by "it doesn't in the same element but two"?

Comment: Your code has Select and Input elements. I want only the Select but lets 2 options, first to press the arrow to display the list and second to press the cell itself to enter color which not in the list. @marsnebulasoup

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer @DanielKahalani. Let me know if it works for you.